# Can TensorFlow Lite can detect material of object and object itself at a time in android studio?

Tags: android, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, machine-learning-model

Is there any way to simultaneously detect the material of any specific object and the object itself in android studio for android applications?

Comment: Hi @Twisha Kotecha, I'm trying to do something similar. Firstly I ran object detection with yolo. Now I want to understand what the object is. I trained classification model with vgg16.  It should work after Yolo. and I'm stuck right here. Maybe you can guide me:)

Comment: Hi @Laura I have done material detection already with some pretrained models but that is not so accurate and lot of things to do with that so I was thinking that combination of both material detection and object detection can fix that. But at this point I'm not sure too, that what can I do for that!! If I'll find something will post here.

Comment: Hello:) @Twisha Kotecha My question is here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697529/classification-model-after-yolo-model    I guess i need to pass the bounding box coordinates through the classification model. but i still don't know exactly where to do it.  I followed here for android yolo. https://github.com/AarohiSingla/TFLite-Object-Detection-Android-App-Tutorial-Using-YOLOv5

Comment: Hi, @Laura it seems like you have done object detection with a bounding box and I have done material detection of objects so which means we both have single- single functionalities but we want them combined, so as per my research we need to train a model in a way which can detect both simultaneously.

Comment: Hello, @Twisha Kotecha, I thought I was going to use more than one model. Example: dinner food detective yolo model, then classification model for soup,main course,salad,dessert then  classification model( for soup: lentil soup, tomato soup, chicken soup; for Main Couse: Fish,Meat, Schnitzel, for Dessert: chocolate cake, macaron)   I have separate .tflite files for each classification model and yolo model. dinnerfood.tflite  ,  SoupMainCourseDessertSalad.tflite, SoupTypesMainCourseTypesDessertTypes.tflite

Comment: Can i run these models after passing through bounding box ? Do I need one model for everything? Please, Can you elaborate? youtube.com/watch?v=ZepT3N6aNFM&t=881s For example in this video he uses separate models, I saw it at 22:01 minutes of this video

Comment: Hi @Laura, 
You can run multiple models in sequence order, but that will be more costly (in time), so it will take longer time to process one frame. The workflow would go smth like this:
1. First you will have to detect the objects, e.g: Drink
2. Then from 1 you will have the coordinates of bbox where that Drink is located
3. Use coordinates from 2. to crop the original frame and take the cropped part
4. Resize it to the dimensions of the second ML model (classifier)
5. The second model (depending on how its trained) will output smth like: Juice, Apple or smth else

Comment: Hi @Notron,  thank you very much for replies. I did object detection. coordinates of bbox : RectF(0.0 ,12.216019, 415.0 412.68738) I found the coordinates in DetectorActivity.java.  How do i pass it through the classification model ?

Comment: @Notron https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697529/classification-model-after-yolo-model  I added the DetectorActivity code here. Should I crop coordinates after object detection ?

Comment: After you have the coordinates you should crop from the original frame that part using this method: Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal, 100, 100,100, 100); , instead of "100" use your coordinates. Then use that cropped bitmap as input for your other model. Its a little hard to write all the logic here without having the app to run and test :/

Comment: Hi @Notron crop part is ok. now how do i run my classification model for types?

Comment: the logic should be similar with running ObjectDetection, you should load the Interpreter the same way (with different ml model), and when you get the cropped bitmap you should rescale it in the dimension that the classification model has and input in the second interpreter. I would suggest to try first with only one image (crop image) just to measure the inference.

Comment: @Notron I can't get the cropped bitmap. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76506244/bounding-box-cropping code snippet here

Answer (score 1):

For future reference I am doing a small recap of my suggestions from the comments section.

There are two ways to "simultaneously detect the material of any specific object and the object itself" or to do smth similar:

1. You train a custom ML model to do that, convert that to .tflite and deploy it on your app (I think from ML side this could be more difficult)
2. You train/get two different ML models, one for object detection (you can find pretrained models for most of the objects, or you train one if you want to detect more specific object), and the other one it can be a classification model, and depending on your use case I think you have to train one yourself, since it very unlikely to find a pretrained model for your use case. Then you will have to run this two models sequentially, first detect the object then classify it.