# Bounding Box Cropping

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop

I did object detection. And I got it in the bounding box. I'm trying to crop inside the bounding box. but it doesn't work. in debug mode, it gets stuck  on the if line.  THANKS!!!

```
         result.setLocation(location);
         mappedRecognitions.add(result);
 
                                    if ((int) location.left > 0 && (int) location.top > 0 && ((int) location.left + (int) location.width()) < xyBitmap.getWidth()
                                          && ((int) location.top + (int) location.height()) < xyBitmap.getHeight()) {
                                     mycroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(xyBitmap,
                                            (int) location.left,
                                            (int) location.top,
                                            (int) location.width(),
                                            (int) location.height()
                                    );                                      
 mycroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mycroppedBitmap, 224, 224, true);
```

Coordinates

[image]
[image]

> DetectorActivity.java File
>
> https://github.com/usertttwm/CropAndClassificationModel/blob/main/DetectorActivity.java
>
> For classification after crop: TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java
>
> https://github.com/usertttwm/CropAndClassificationModel/blob/main/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel

NEW!!!!!!

```
if (1==1) {

mycroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap,
1,1,224,224

);

final String resultLabel = detector1.recognizeImage1(mycroppedBitmap);
```

RESULTS
croppedBitmap

[image: croppedBitmap]
mycroppedBitmap

[image]

DETECTIVE (I'm trying to crop the bounding box)

[image]

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
 mappedRecognitions.add(result);//TRAY DETECTIVE
                            Bitmap copyOfOriginalBitmap = rgbFrameBitmap.copy(rgbFrameBitmap.getConfig(), true);
                            Bitmap secondBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(copyOfOriginalBitmap,
                                    (int)  location.left, (int)location.top, (int)location.right, (int)location.bottom);
                            Bitmap secondScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(secondBitmap, 224, 224, true);

                            final String resultLabel = detector1.recognizeImage1(secondScaledBitmap);
```

[image: error]

CROP WORKİNG UPDATE

```
 result.setLocation(location);
                        mappedRecognitions.add(result);
                        Bitmap copyOfOriginalBitmap = rgbFrameBitmap.copy(rgbFrameBitmap.getConfig(), true);
                        Bitmap secondBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(copyOfOriginalBitmap,
                                (int)location.left, (int)location.top, (int)location.right-(int)location.left, (int)location.bottom-(int)location.top);
                        Bitmap secondScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(secondBitmap, 224, 224, true);

                        final String resultLabel = detector1.recognizeImage1(secondScaledBitmap);
```

CROP
[image: cropTray]

------------------RESOURCES--------------

https://github.com/AarohiSingla/TFLite-Object-Detection-Android-App-Tutorial-Using-YOLOv5    I used it for object detection with yolo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepT3N6aNFM&t=881s
https://github.com/ivangrov/TensorFlow-Lite-Age-Gender-Estimation-on-Android/blob/main/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java

I used it to pass through the crop and classification model.

Comment: @Notron  It gets stuck in the if part

Comment: what do you mean with "gets stuck", try to print out the location and see if that is a valid one.

Comment: stuck -> , The if block doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Notron,  location.left = 304.87216
location.top = 173.75671
location.width = ?does not appear
location.height = ?does not appear

xyBitmap:
mHeight:360
mWidth = 640
and, I updated the question.  I deleted the if block, it give this error:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a little hard to debug this without the code and the information that you provided, but here are some clear steps on how I would solve this and maybe you can check on your side and see where your bug is.
What I can see is that you are trying to crop the second image from the first cropped image, which is wrong, you should try to crop the image for the second interpreter from the original image, so the process should look smth like this:

1. First create a copy of the original bitmap (since you are scaling it down)

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = ...; // your original bitmap here
Bitmap copyOfOriginalBitmap = originalBitmap.copy(originalBitmap.getConfig(), true);
```

2. After you run first interpreter (using originalBitmap) you will get the results that coordinates are in range from 0 to width or height of the Interpreter input (this can change, on your logs I see that coordinates are scaled up which is what we need)

```
Recognition myObject = ...; // you can get the detection that you want here, you can do this with a simple for loop
// now create second bitmap by cropping the original and using the scaled up coordinates
Bitmap secondBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(copyOfOriginalBitmap, myObject.location.left, myObject.location.top, myObject.location.right, myObject.location.bottom)
// now create the second scaled bitmap for your second Interpreter with the width and height of the interpreter size
Bitmap secondScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(secondBitmap, width, height, true)
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Is rgbFrameBitmap the original Bitmap ? I want to show you all the codes.

Comment: rgbFrameBitmap is all the image the camera sees. @Notron

Comment: yes, from the links you provided I am guessing that the rgbFrameBitmap should be the originalBitmap in this case

Comment: UPDATE!!!! I added it to the question.  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()   it showed this error @Notron

Comment: in which line of code was this error ?

Comment: Bitmap secondBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(copyOfOriginalBitmap,
                                        (int)location.left, (int)location.top, (int)location.right, (int)location.bottom);    this line

Comment: for the width and height (third and fourth parameter) use (location.right - location.left) and (location.bottom - location.top)

Comment: yes, @Notron I changed and crop is working. I added Bitmap view to the question for testing. Thank you very much:) , this is very good. your advices is excellent:) but the classification is not working correctly. I will ask you questions for classification.

Comment: https://github.com/usertttwm/CropAndClassificationModel/blob/main/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel   The cropped bitmap image goes here. My classification names: Breakfast tray and dinner tray. but the result is always the breakfast tray.           List<String> foodList = Arrays.asList("breakfast tray", "dinner tray");   What can I do ? @Notron

Comment: This one looks like an issue on the ML model side, maybe the model is not trained with that kind of data or needs to be trained more so it can classify correctly.

Comment: The efficient net model was used for training. I viewed the .tflite model in netron.app  https://github.com/usertttwm/CropAndClassificationModel/blob/main/zsaved_AksamSabah_EfficientNetV2S_model.tflite.svg  I added it here. Is it the part on the android or the model is wrong ?  I couldn't understand here. @Notron

Comment: I am guessing that the part of the model is wrong, if you haven't train it then maybe the model doesn't know how to classify your images. You can try to run the same model in python and see if it gives you the same results

Comment: I have two classes. There are 130 images from each class.  I tried vgg16 but it didn't work.  What can you advices ? @Notron https://github.com/sbouslama/Image-classification-using-CNN-Vgg16-keras/blob/master/Meuble_classification.ipynb   i tried this but i couldn't update the size.  It's set to 100 but output is 512.

Comment: Now, there are 300 images from each class.

Comment: I think this is related to Machine Learning part, the advice is to train the model with the images and try different steps and also test it in python before deploying it to android, otherwise this is a general ML problem and doesn't have a "right" answer for it.

Comment: Hi @Notron ,I trained a new model for classification. I followed here. github.com/ayushdabra/ImageClassificationProject-IITK/blob/… The result is correct in the test images. but android is wrong

Comment: I think that this is a separate question, feel free to create a new question with more details about your problem

Comment: Hello @Notron The problem is in the Machine Learning model part. You are absolutely right.  https://medium.com/@draj0718/image-classification-and-prediction-using-transfer-learning-3cf2c736589d   I did it as in this paper. It works correctly on Android(.tflite) too.  Thank you very much:)

Comment: Hello @Notron I have a new question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77372206/object-detective-shift-issue-on-andro%c4%b0d    I would be very happy if you tell me your opinion.