# OBJECT DETECTIVE SHIFT ISSUE On ANDROİD

Tags: java, android, image-processing, object-detection, yolo

I used two yolov5 models. My first model detects the tray. In my second model, it finds food types.

The size of the first model was 416, then I cropped it. I sent it to the second model. The size of my second model is 224. my question: There is a shift in the second model.

I think, The reason for the shift problem is crop . It detective the food in the cropped image. Draws the result for the original image. It should change according to the center of the tray.  I understand the problem, but I didn't understand how to change it.
[image: Table]
I created a table in debug mode. I wrote the values.
Do I need to increase xPos and yPos values when drawing? There are only location values in the MultiBoxerTracker file. bottom, left right, top. I'm so confused.

```
Yolov5Classifier2.java coordinate part
    public ArrayList<Recognition> recognizeImage2(Bitmap bitmap) {
  final float xPos = out[0][i][0];
                final float yPos = out[0][i][1];

                final float w = out[0][i][2];
                final float h = out[0][i][3];
                Log.d("secondyolov5",
                        Float.toString(xPos) + ',' + yPos + ',' + w + ',' + h);
                final RectF rect =
                        new RectF( Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                                Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));




                detections.add(new Recognition("" + offset, labels.get(detectedClass),


                        confidenceInClass, rect, detectedClass));}
```

MultiTracker2.java part of draw

```
  public synchronized void draw(final Canvas canvas,float kayabi,float kayabla ) {
    
    final boolean rotated = sensorOrientation % 180 == 90;
    final float multiplier =
            Math.min(
                    canvas.getHeight() / (float) (rotated ? frameWidth : frameHeight),
                    canvas.getWidth() / (float) (rotated ? frameHeight : frameWidth));
    frameToCanvasMatrix =
            ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
                    frameWidth,
                    frameHeight,
                    (int) (multiplier * (rotated ? frameHeight : frameWidth)),
                    (int) (multiplier * (rotated ? frameWidth : frameHeight)),
                    sensorOrientation,
                    false);
    for (final TrackedRecognition recognition : trackedObjects) {

      final RectF trackedPos = new RectF(recognition.location);




      getFrameToCanvasMatrix().mapRect(trackedPos);



      boxPaint.setColor(recognition.color);

      float cornerSize = Math.min(trackedPos.width(), trackedPos.height()) / 8.0f;

      canvas.drawRoundRect(trackedPos, cornerSize, cornerSize, boxPaint);


      final String labelString =
              !TextUtils.isEmpty(recognition.title)
                      ? String.format("%s %.2f", recognition.title, (100 * recognition.detectionConfidence))
                      : String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition.detectionConfidence));
      //            borderedText.drawText(canvas, trackedPos.left + cornerSize, trackedPos.top,
      // labelString);
      borderedText.drawText(
              canvas, trackedPos.left + cornerSize, trackedPos.top, labelString + "%", boxPaint);
    }
  }
```